# error with regex \(.+?(\d+)\)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove from a tetxt any parenthesis that end with a number. So I use this regex :  `\(.+?(\d+)\)`

This regex remove the text like (1980) or  (pp. 100) but it will also remove the whole phrase below:

```
(etc) and new frontiers in Social Neuroscience (pp. 127-151)
```

Which regex will ignore the first parenthesis above?

Comment: Check [`\([^)]+\d+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/oS6mE5/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\([^)]*\d+\)
```

You need to use this.Your regex fails on `(etc) and new frontiers in Social Neuroscience (pp. 127-151)` as it says find a `(` then find the first `\d` which is `127` here and the find `)`.